# What order for Store and Design System in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am new to react and using Redux and Chakra. My index.tsx is set up like this:

```
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>
    </ChakraProvider>
  </Provider>
```

Im curious if the `Provider` should be the outermost, or the `ChakraProvider` or even maybe the `React.StrictMode`. What order should they surround `App`? Thanks